# Alternative to iterating through multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy, loops, vectorization, numba

I try to make multidimensional calculation in numpy but it uses all the RAM, making it impossible to run.

```
S1 = np.arange(0,601,2)
d0 = np.random.randint(0, 200, size=(107, 3))
d1 = np.random.randint(0, 200, size=(107, 3))

for S in S1:
    retorno = +\
        + (np.maximum(S - d0.T[0], 0) - d0.T[2])[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + \
        + (np.maximum(S - d0.T[0], 0) - d0.T[2])[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + \
        + (np.maximum(S - d0.T[0], 0) - d0.T[2])[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + \
        + (np.maximum(S - d0.T[0], 0) - d0.T[2])[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + \
        + (np.maximum(S - d0.T[0], 0) - d0.T[2])[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + \
        + (np.maximum(d1.T[0] - S, 0) - d1.T[2])[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + \
        + (np.maximum(d1.T[0] - S, 0) - d1.T[2])[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + \
        + (np.maximum(d1.T[0] - S, 0) - d1.T[2])[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + \
        + (np.maximum(d1.T[0] - S, 0) - d1.T[2])[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis] + \
        + (np.maximum(d1.T[0] - S, 0) - d1.T[2])[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
```

I tried with loops too, but that's not a possible option, because it takes much long to compute.

I need a way to iterate throug it fastly enough or a way to deal with all this data without spending much computer resources. Also, it needs to be compatible with numba in order to increse speed and efficiency.

Note that this data is just a small example.

Comment: Please give more detail about the size of the lists and the types of operations. Also, why can't you use numba?

Comment: Do you relly need lists (intead of simple numpy arrays)? Apart from that, please provide a fully, working code including some maybe random inputs.

Comment: The shape of the arrays are (50,3) each. And actually, I need numba because it provides higher optimization for running in limited resource machines

Comment: and no, I don't need lists. Np arrays can work well and have compatibility with numba.njit

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There will never be a "fastly" way to iterate through a 100GB array.  Have you done the math to figure out how much memory this require?  You need to come up with a different approach.  Your solutions must fit the resources you fave.

Comment: It would really help to make the example small enough to understand easily, and to show exactly what the result should look like. It looks like the result will be sparse?